# How can I call a method with parameter mouse event e in another class?

Tags: java

I write the code below and want to call the mousepress method in another class, but I get the error to define parameter mouseevent for where I called it, but I get `NullPointerException` error when I define a variable mouseevent `e`.

Please help me.

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e , int tankid) { 
     System.out.println("insert which tanks you want to move");
      JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
      System.out.println(clicked.getAlignmentX()+"mmmmmmmmmmm");
        for(int x = 0; x<board.r; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0;y<board.cc;y++)
            {
                if(clicked == board.squares[x][y])
                {

                             ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/win_10/Desktop/tanks/tank1.png");
                             board.squares[troops[tankid].getPosition().x][troops[tankid].getPosition().y].setIcon(null);
                             board.squares[x][y].setIcon(icon);
                             map.mapboard[troops[tankid].getPosition().x][troops[tankid].getPosition().y].setBackground(null);
                             troops[i].getPosition().x = x;
                             troops[i].getPosition().x = y;
                             map.mapboard[troops[tankid].getPosition().x][troops[tankid].getPosition().x].add(new JLabel(name));
                             SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(map.getContentPane());
                   System.out.println(x + " "+ y);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your language, but I think a _listener_ should be calling the mouse click handler method, rather than you directly.

Comment: Depending on how much you need our help, you will likely want to consider improving this question a lot. Start by explaining just what you're trying to do *and **why***, and then consider creating and posting a valid [mcve], a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification. . Note that this is code posted as code-formatted text and not as a link to an off-site resource.

Comment: Also, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a short demo that may help get you started.
Basically you create the listener in the class that need to respond to the mouse click (Moo) and add it to a component in the class which generates the mouse event:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    private JButton btn;

    Foo(){

        super("Foo frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        btn = new JButton("Click Me");
        getContentPane().add(btn);

        validate();
        pack();
    }

    JButton getBtn() {
        return btn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Moo moo = new Moo();
        foo.getBtn().addMouseListener(moo.getMouseListener());
        foo.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Moo {

    Moo() {}

    MouseListener getMouseListener() {

        return new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println("Mouse pressed ! ");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you need more clarifications don't hesitate to ask.